# What is this status bar icon for

Tags: notification-icons, 7.1-nougat

Since I upgraded my s7 edge to nougat I am seeing this icon with circle quater of which is white and the rest dim and a plus sign in center.  There seems to be no  info in notification panel     [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That indicates that Data Saver is turned On in Settings - Data Usage.